# Data insertion to iceberg table using pyiceberg API

Tags: apache-iceberg

How to insert the data to iceberg table using pyiceberg API? How can we use glue catalog here?

```
                from pyiceberg.catalog import load_catalog
                catalog = load_catalog("glue", **{"type": "glue"})
                iceberg_table = catalog.load_table(f"{database}.{table}")
```

when I am running the script in EC2 I am getting NoRegionError()
ERROR: you must specify region